# How to pass a conditional flag into a class method without using global in PHP

Tags: php, oop

In **PHP** I have an `Error` class that handles all errors in my application. Its method signature is:

```
class Error {
    public static function show($code, $message) { ... }
}
```

Other classes such `Database`, `Memcached`, `Settings` call `Error::show()` if an error happens inside of themselves. I have a special case where, I want `Error::show()` to update a record in MongoDB before performing its normal logic. However, I don't want to add a new function parameter like `is_special_case` into the `Error::show()` method because that would require passing a flag around to every single class and function that calls `Error`.

I am thinking I could set a global `global $is_special_case = true` then inside of `Error::show()` check if that global is set, but this just feels wrong, and poor practice. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: It is (using globals) as bad as using static methods.

Comment: Why would you create an instance of `Error?`. No need.

Comment: "No need" --- then use global variables. No reason to improve something that is intentionally terrible.

Comment: I'm open to removing **static** but when would I need a instance of `Error`?

Comment: Is it used across the application and is required by (mostly) all components? Then at the application bootstrap procedure.

Comment: So my proposal: make the current error non-static. Then create a decorator that handles that special case. In bootstrap instantiate a decorator with error instance and use it in the app. That way - the "special logic" is encapsulated separately from the `Error` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `Default parameters` where it is always set to false. And in the case it is true you can handle that instance.

```
  function doSomething($isSomethingWrong = false){...}
```

Yes you are going to have to change your functions definitions but you don't have to pass it in every time and you can when you need too.

Comment: But all the classes such as `Database` would need to have this flag passed in as well on the special case, since they callout to `Error` themselve.

Comment: Still cleaner then global

Comment: This literally would be insanely ugly and require lots of changes. Instead of `Database::connect()`, I'd need `Database::connect($is_special_case)`. I think the real fix, is not to do the Error logic inside of classes, but return true or false, and let the outer code call Error.

Comment: That is a good alternative if you don't want to handle this in the class itself. But now you have to change the code to `return true or false or 1 or 0 or the error code itself` and pass in parameters by reference when you wanted it to be returned. Either way you have to change a good amount of code.

Comment: What if I set a property in the `Error` class. `Error::$is_special_case = true`. Then just check that? The set property will persist across all calls to `Error`.

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of your code. I don't know what functions are used by who or what. But if you think that you are only going to have 1 special case then do that. You should consider passing in a `error code number`. So in the case you think of more then you don't have to change the code. Or if you want to display them differently